# Intent from executors for reciever is not sent

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, executorservice

I can’t catch up - how to send Toast from Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor () in the run () method? In the debug I set a breakpoint, everything is fine, we go into the method, but the message does not appear in the emulator? And yet, in the same method, I send the intent to the receiver, the intent is sent, but the receiver does not receive it.

ExecutorService service:

```
public void start() {
    service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    service.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_FOR_FRAGMENT);
            sendBroadcast(intent);
            service.shutdown();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, you can close the question. The essence of the problem was that I did not correctly implement the service methods.